# Prove/Show that Limit is equal to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits, improper-integrals

I'm really struggling on this question.  I've been thinking about it for awhile now but this is one of those where I don't really have much intuition on what to do.

> **Problem 3.** Prove that if the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x) =: L$ exists (finite or infinity) and the improper integral. $$\int_a^{+\infty}f(x) dx$$
> is convergent, then $L = 0$.

Here is some facts that I know that I think I should perhaps use.

Facts/Knowledge I know:
The above integral can be rewritten as:

> $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{A\to \infty}\int_a^{A}f(x)dx$$

We know that limit as x goest to infinity of $f(x)=L$.  I need to somehow show that limit L is equal to 0.
If I take the integral I get $\lim_{A \to \infty} F(A)-f(a)$ and I know this does not equal infinity as the integral converges.  I'm not sure if this is on the right track or what to do next.

I was thinking maybe perhaps instead I could use the Cauchy Criterion to come up with a proof.  Note: I'm not used to doing proofs with Improper integrals.

> **Theorem 1** (Cauchy Criterion). *The improper integral* (1) *converges if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $M\geqslant a$ so that for all $A, B \geqslant M$ we have*
>
> $$\Bigg|\int_A^B f(x) dx\Bigg| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 8):

Assume that $L\in(0,\infty)$, then for some $M$, we have $f(x)>\dfrac{L}{2}$ for all $x\geq M$, then $\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}f(x)dx\geq\int_{M}^{\infty}\dfrac{L}{2}dx=\infty$.

If $L\in(-\infty,0)$, then for some $N$, we have $f(x)<\dfrac{L}{2}$ for all $x\geq N$, then $\displaystyle\int_{N}^{\infty}f(x)dx\leq\int_{N}^{\infty}\dfrac{L}{2}dx=-\infty$.

Similar reasoning applies for the case that $L=\infty$ or $L=-\infty$. For example, $L=\infty$: Simply choose $M'$ such that $f(x)>1$ for all $x\geq M'$, the integrating both sides on $[M',\infty)$ to get the contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how does this show that L=0.

Comment: Essentially by considering the cases that $L$ being real number differs from zero, and that plus or minus infinity, we get contradiction in each case, so $L$ must be zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand several things.

Comment: 1. Why does f(x)>L/2 whenever x>M and f(x)<L/2 for x>N?                                2. How do we get a contradiction in each case and how does similar reasoning apply for the case L=infinity or L=-infinity?

Comment: Just the application of the definition of limit: Take $\epsilon_{0}=L/2$ (assume that $L>0$), then there exists some $M$ such that for all $x\geq M$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon_{0}=L/2$, breaking the absolute value, then $f(x)>L-L/2=L/2$.

Comment: Thanks I got that. But I don't really understand how the cases that L=infinity or L=-infinity works?

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: Thanks, I just don't understand how integrating both sides on [M', infinity) to get the contradiction.  Sorry just trying to understand, having difficulty understanding this topic.

Comment: Then the right side is just $\infty$, the same contradiction that we got for $L>0$ case. As you know if we say that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ exists, then so must be $\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ for any $M$, so $\displaystyle\int_{M}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ must be a real number, hence it cannot greater or equal with $\infty$.

Comment: So the contradiction for all the cases is that the integral must be a real number as it is convergent but we are getting that it is greater than or equal to infinity or less than or equal to -infinity.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want to say.

Comment: can you explain why theintegral of L/2 equal to inifiny ?